# expressjs passport mongodb session not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, passport.js

I use passport.js + express.js + mongodb, I think it is a very descent way to implement server authentication, however, I found some weird.

To setup the session storage:

```
  // CookieParser should be above session
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(cookieSession({ secret: 'secret' }));
  app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: pkg.name,
    store: new mongoStore({
      url: config.db    
    })
  }));

  // use passport session
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
```

Then,  whenever I log in, I check my mongodb, but find no `sessions` collection.

Anyone knows why?

Thanks.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing how you have required `mongoStore` and the output of `config.db`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but from what I understand the the user session created by passport js is not stored in the db. When a sessions begins it will go to your db and grab the user info. If the user info exists then it will attach the session to req.user. At no point does it actually save the session to the db unless you add custom functionally to store session info once the session is initalized. Maybe [this article](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/) will help you understand a bit more what is going on. If you would like to save the session info maybe create a model that will accept the information stored in a req.user and have it save once a session has began.

Comment: Great thanks, I figure out this right after posting this question, but I am wondering whenever passport loads db, there will be a cost. I am wondering if it may use too much resource?

Comment: pt1 - I do not believe there is a way around it. Unless you are storing the user information on a  flat file hosted within your application(not recommended) then it will need to access the db to verify that they are a user.

Comment: pt2 - You could possibly have your server pull all users from db and just store them into a list and then scan the db for a new user to add it to the list when a new user is created to update the list holding the users that way it will only have to touch the db once a new user is created and not when users are logging in. It will verify against the list of users it has in memory already.

Comment: pt3 -That being said I do not think it is a good idea to have all of your users info just hanging out inside of your application and for security purposes I would recommend not taking this approach either. Sorry if this does not answer your question maybe you could rephrase a little to help me understand better what you are asking.

Comment: alright, what I mean is passport keeps querying database whenever there is an incoming request to server. Take a imagination, if there are tons of users who request APIs and each API will call db once for session check, it will be a big cost, because for most of time, database is stored in disk. I am wondering if there is a better way to help passport verify user session. As your answer above, I don't think it works better. MongoDB is sort of dependent a lot on memory. I think it may be not that painful to do session check each time?

Comment: I am sorry I do not know the best method to do that. pt2 of my explanation seems to be the idea you are looking for. If you want to keep them inside of the applications memory and not have to retrieve from db then have your create new user code save the users directly to a list inside of your application and then verify against that list of users once you are attempting to start a user.session.This would only work if the server has 100% uptime and would lose the list of users once it got shut down or restarted. I do not recommend this but I could be wrong and there is probably better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [`cookie-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) module and the [`express-sesion`](https://github.com/expressjs/session) module.  These two middlewares are fighting each other.  Both modules implement sessions, and you need to use only one of the two.
`cookie-session` storers sessions in cookies, and in your case `express-session` will store your sessions in Mongo.
Which one you choose is up to your application requirements.

**The details** around your issue are that, since its first in middleware stack, `cookie-session` is creating a `req.session` property.  Then the `express-session` code sees that this property already exists and decides to do nothing.  This is why Mongo is not showing sessions.